# Android: Getting user input (Soft keys) on a new thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, apk, progressdialog

I cant seem to get the soft keys input to work while the main UI is on a new thread. I want to make it so when they hit the Back soft key it will toast or something.

Source Code:
http://pastebin.com/8gh41j9c

Thanks!

Comment: People don't want to click on a link to a giant blob of code, please post a small, relevant snippet of code into the question itself instead.  Also, your question is not clear.  You want to catch input from a thread other than the UI thread?  I don't think that is possible.

Answer (score 0):

> while the main UI is on a new thread

The "main UI" is never on "a new thread". The "main UI" is not on "a new thread" in the code you linked to.

> I want to make it so when they hit the Back soft key it will toast or something.

Override `onBackPressed()` for Android 2.x devices.